# Apply indeterminate, tabulated filters to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table of demographics records in the database.

```
| biDemographicId | biPostId | vcDemographicType | vcDemographicValue |
|-----------------|----------|-------------------|--------------------|
|               1 |        1 | country           | CA                 |
|               2 |        1 | language          | FR                 |
|               3 |        1 | platform          | IOS                |
|               4 |        2 | country           | US                 |
|               5 |        2 | language          | EN                 |
|               6 |        2 | platform          | IOS                |
|               7 |        3 | country           | US                 |
|               8 |        3 | language          | ES                 |
|               9 |        3 | platform          | WEB                |
```

Say I want the only the records where:

- Country is CA *or* US
- Language is FR.
- Platform is IOS.

These filters are passed in as XML and then tabulated:

```
<Demographics>
    <Demographic type="country">US</Demographic>
    <Demographic type="country">CA</Demographic>
    <Demographic type="lang">FR</Demographic>
    <Demographic type="platform">IOS</Demographic>
</Demographics>

| vcFilterType | vcFilterValue |
|--------------|---------------|
| language     | FR            |
| country      | CA            |
| country      | US            |
| platform     | IOS           |
```

My desired result would be the following:

```
| biDemographicId | biPostId | vcDemographicType | vcDemographicValue |
|-----------------|----------|-------------------|--------------------|
|               1 |        1 | country           | CA                 |
|               2 |        1 | language          | FR                 |
|               3 |        1 | platform          | IOS                |
```

Or more generally:

```
{
  { posts | type=type1 & value=value1,1 } 
  ∪ ... 
  ∪ { posts | type=type1 & value=value1,N }
}
∩
...
∩
{
  { posts | type=typeM & value=valueN,1 } 
  ∪ ... 
  ∪ { posts | type=typeM & value=valueM,N }
}
```

With a filter table:

```
| vcFilterType | vcFilterValue |
|--------------|---------------|
| type1        | value1,1      |
| ...          | ...           |
| type1        | value1,N      |
| ...          | ...           |
| typeM        | valueM,1      |
| ...          | ...           |
| typeM        | valueM,N      |
```

My issue is that the types and values are variables, so I cannot just do `WHERE type = 'country' AND value = 'CA'`.

Comment: Build a dynamic query in whatever development language you use.

Comment: Those filters are passed into what?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have the data table and the filtering table already defined:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [biDemographicId] INT
   ,[biPostId] INT
   ,[vcDemographicType] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[vcDemographicValue] VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([biDemographicId], [biPostId], [vcDemographicType], [vcDemographicValue])
VALUES (1, 1, 'country', 'CA')
      ,(2, 1, 'language', 'FR')
      ,(3, 1, 'platform', 'IOS')
      ,(4, 2, 'country', 'US')
      ,(5, 2, 'language', 'EN')
      ,(6, 2, 'platform', 'IOS')
      ,(7, 3, 'country', 'US')
      ,(8, 3, 'language', 'ES')
      ,(9, 3, 'platform', 'WEB');

DECLARE @FilterDataSource TABLE
(
    [vcFilterType] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[vcFilterValue] VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @FilterDataSource ([vcFilterType], [vcFilterValue])
VALUES ('language', 'FR')
      ,('country', 'CA')
      ,('country', 'US')
      ,('platform', 'IOS');
```

What we can do is to count the `DISTINCT` filtering types - for, example in your case we have `3` distinct filtering types - `language`, `country` and `platform.`

We need to get only these records, which are matching the values of these three types:

```
DECLARE @DistinctFilteringCriteria TINYINT;

SELECT @DistinctFilteringCriteria = COUNT(DISTINCT [vcFilterType])
FROM @FilterDataSource;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS.*
          ,COUNT([vcDemographicType]) OVER (PARTITION BY [biPostId]) AS [FilteringCriteriaMatched]
    FROM @DataSource DS
    INNER JOIN @FilterDataSource FDS
        ON DS.[vcDemographicType] = FDS.[vcFilterType]
        AND DS.[vcDemographicValue] = FDS.[vcFilterValue]
)
SELECT [biDemographicId], [biPostId], [vcDemographicType], [vcDemographicValue]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [FilteringCriteriaMatched] = @DistinctFilteringCriteria;
```

That's it:

[image]

Comment: Like it! Clever approach!